# jquery form validation on button click and then send data on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Hi i have this code in my project.here i wanted to validate my form on button click and then i want to 
run another function(searchdata()) from the same button click. when i run the code its only run the searchdata function. i need first to run the validation then to run the searchdata  function.
searchdata funtion is on the court.js file

Here is the code

```
<?php include('session.php'); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Release Prisoner</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/court-home.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/release.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/release.js"></script>
  <script src="js/court.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fm2").validate({
      rules:{
        look_case_no:"required",                    
      },
      messages:{                    
        look_case_no:"enter valid case no",                 
      }
    });
    $("#search").click(function() {
      $("#fm2").valid();
    });
  });    
  </script>    
</head>

<body>        
<div id="wrapper">              
  <form id="fm2" name="fm2">
  <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Case No</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="text" name="look_case_no" id="look_case_no">
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>      
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" name="search" id="search" onClick="searchdata();" value="Search"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>        
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the `searchdata()` function in `court.js`:

```
function searchdata() {
  var look_case_no = document.getElementById("look_case_no").value;
  // var look_reg_no = document.getElementById("look_reg_no").value; 
  var url = "court_search_view.php?RequestType=searchview"; 
  url +="&look_case_no="+look_case_no; 
  //url +="&look_reg_no="+look_reg_no; 
  htmlobj = $.ajax({
              url:url,
              async:false
            }); 
  document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML = htmlobj.responseText; 
  var tblMain = document.getElementById("tblMain"); 
}
```

Comment: where is your method 'searchdata() '?

Comment: Why not put them in the same event handler?

Comment: @Rohit   function searchdata()
 {
  var look_case_no   = document.getElementById("look_case_no").value;
 // var look_reg_no     = document.getElementById("look_reg_no").value;
  
  var url = "court_search_view.php?RequestType=searchview";
    
     url +="&look_case_no="+look_case_no;
  //url +="&look_reg_no="+look_reg_no;  
  
 htmlobj=$.ajax({url:url,async:false});

 document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML = htmlobj.responseText;
 var tblMain = document.getElementById("tblMain");
  
  
 }

Comment: please any good answer?

Comment: please add this code to the question

Comment: @dwhite.me   what is the code? and where is it?

Answer (score 2):

The [`$.valid()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid) method checks whether the form is valid **AFTER** the [$.validate()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) method is called. In other words, it doesn't do the form validation.

Replace your `$("#search").click` event handler with:

```
$("#search").click(function() {
  $("#fm2").validate();
  if($("#fm2").valid())
    searchdata();
});
```